# Volume comparison for minimal submanifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, curvature, minimal-surfaces

I am reading the book "*A course in Minimal Surfaces*" by Colding and Minicozzi. 
I don't understand a step in the proof of Corollary 1.13.

Let $\Sigma^k \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a $k$-dimensional minimal submanifold. Fix $x_0 \in \Sigma$.
I want to study the behaviour of the function:
$$
s\mapsto \Theta_{x_0}(s) \,\, \colon = \frac{ \text{Vol}\big( B_s(x_0) \cap \Sigma \big) }{\text{Vol}\big(B_s \subset \mathbb{R}^k \big)}
$$ 
where $B_s(x_0)$ is the $n$-dimensional euclidean ball of radius $s$ centred in $x_0$ and $B_s$ is the $k$-dimensional euclidean ball of radius $s$ centred in the origin.

I know that $\Theta_{x_0}(s)$ is monotone nondecreasing.

I want to show that 
$$
\Theta_{x_0}(s) \ge 1.
$$
In the book, the authors say that since **$\Sigma$ is smooth and proper, it is infinitesimally Euclidean and hence**
$$
\lim_{s \rightarrow 0}\Theta_{x_0}(s) \ge 1.
$$

Can you explain me this better?

Answer (score 1):

If $\Sigma$ is smooth and proper then for $x_0\in \Sigma$, we know that $\exists$ a small ball in $\mathbb{R^k}$ around $x_0$ (by the definition of a manifold). But the ball can intersect $M$ multiple times (but it intersect $M$ at least once).

So the numerator in the definition of $\Theta$ is the number of times the ball intersects $M$ and hence $\lim_{s\to 0}\Theta_{x_0}(s)\geq 1$.